# simulating a discrete markov process from a reducible transition rate matrix

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, transition-matrix

I'm trying to model an irreversible, discrete Markov process. I have a set of states $S$ arranged in a tree-like structure (it is only possible to move from parent vertex to child vertex). I compute the transition rates of parent-to-child arcs (the transition rates are assumed to parametrize exponential random variables characterizing the time to transition), and I aggregate the transition rates in an upper-triangular, weighted Laplacian matrix $L$.

From what I understand, the weighted Laplacian $L$ is the transition rate matrix ([infinitesimal generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_rate_matrix)) describing the rate a continuous Markov chain will transition between states. Based on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/561677/transition-probability-in-continuous-time-markov-chain-ctmc?rq=1) question, to simulate from the transition rate matrix, it seems that I need the transition probability matrix (a [stochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix)).

How might I simulate trajectories from the transition rate matrix given in $L$? Since my process is irreversible, must I take into account the exponential distribution of transition times, or is there an alternative way to "convert" $L$ to a transition probability matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is this (it does not require the structure of a tree). Assume: 
\begin{align}
S &= \mbox{State space}\\
(q_{ij}) &= \mbox{transition rates} \\
v_i &= \sum_{j \in S: j \neq i} q_{ij}
\end{align}

- When you enter a new state $i$, independently generate an exponentially distributed random variable $T_i$ with parameter $v_i$.  The time $T_i$ is the time you stay in state $i$.
- After time $T_i$, independently transition to a new state $j \in S$ according to transition probabilities: 
  $$ P_{ij} = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 
  \frac{q_{ij}}{v_i} \quad  & \mbox{ if $j \neq i$}\\
  0 & \mbox{ if $i=j$}\end{array}\right. $$
  Notice that these probabilities indeed sum to 1: $\sum_{j\in S}P_{ij} = 1$.

Comment: essentially Gillespie?

Comment: I do not know what "essentially Gillespie" means.

Comment: Sorry, basically this is the Gillespie algorithm?

Comment: I have not heard that term before.  Yet, if you already know some algorithm, what was the point of your question?

Comment: A related method of "uniformization" allows for self-transitions with rates $q_{ii}\geq 0$ and treats $v_i=v$ for all $i \in S$ (constant) where $q_{ii}$ is simply chosen to impose this constant condition. The advantage of such uniformization is that if you skip the generation of the exponential variables $T_i$  and just stay in each state for one unit of time, then the steady state in this "embedded discrete time chain" is the same as the true steady state.

Comment: Ah, from a quick search, I believe that this falls under "kinetic/dynamic monte carlo"